# React.js displayed values not matching parent state and rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a to-do list type app to learn React. I have an `App` component, which contains a `Todolist` component, which contains `ListItem` components. Each `ListItem` component has a title and a boolean `completed` which is controlled by a checkbox.

`ListItem` components that are checked and completed are sorted to the bottom of the `Todolist`. When an item is checked, I call a function `setItemCompleted()` (passed down in props from `App`) to update `App`'s state and re-render everything.

In `setItemCompleted()` I print the updated array of `ListItem` and it matches what I expect it to be. When React re-renders everything and I open the Chrome inspector to check the rendered HTML, it also matches what I expect it to be. The problem is, the actual `ListItem` that are displayed on the page do not match either of these; instead of the checked off item moving to the bottom of the page, the last item in the list gets checked.

Here is a "minimal, complete, and reproducible" example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-su7iw?file=/index.js

Comment: Please include a copy of the Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example of the code with issue in your question. The code in the sandbox can change, or the sandbox removed entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use index as `ListItem` key which is not recommended and in your case causes these issues. Change from `key={i}` to `key={item.itemID}` and it should fix these issues.

Comment: Thank you SO much, I was scratching my head at this for the longest time.